# Running Javascript with CScript?

Tags: windows-7, windows, javascript, wsh

I'm trying to learn how to run Javascript (instead of VBScript) using CScript.exe, but when I try, I get an error:

```
cscript temp.js
Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".js".
```

I [thought](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by8safft) this is possible -- any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [turns out](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/fix-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension/95d58867-3f31-45e3-aeaf-32ecea4d33c1) that the `.js` extension wasn't associated with `JSFile` in the registry. Doing so fixed the problem.

Answer (score 24):

Setting the registry with regsvr32 did not work for me. Also, I don't want it, since I want my .js to be linked with a plain text editor.

But there is a command line option `//E` for cscript which makes the job:

```
cscript //E:jscript hello.js
```

Comment: This answer is best if you don't want to replace your file association.

Answer (score 23):

A very simple fix: use [assoc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/assoc.mspx?mfr=true).

```
c:\>assoc .js=JSFile
```

(Mine had become associated with a text editor at some point.)

Comment: I'd associated .js with text editor on purpose, its very easy to confuse this error with something else.

Answer (score 11):

It's worth to mention that [rplantiko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156674/1348138) works even if the
extension of the filename is not .js. This allows for putting .js code
into a .cmd file and running as a batch, forming a single-file
solution that is fully portable without preliminary steps (like
`assoc`).

For example, if you create a `test.cmd` file with the following content,
you'll be able to run it by simply clicking on it in Explorer,
or by drag&drop another file over its icon:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
  @cscript //Nologo //E:jscript "%~f0" "test arg" %* & pause & goto :eof
@end
WScript.Echo("hello world");
for (var i = 0, n = WScript.Arguments.Length, args = []; i < n; ++i)
    args.push(WScript.Arguments(i));
WScript.Echo("arguments: " + args.join(","));
```

The lines between `@then` ... `@end` are batch commands interpreted by cmd.exe. The last command is `goto :eof` to skip the rest of the file. The lines after `@end` are interpreted by cscript.exe.

Comment: Very nice! :)  Probably 99% people only know and use the very basics of cmd scripts[1], so this adds a massive amount of power for very little fuss. Definitely one for the snippets collection, thanks.

[1] Ok, don't flame me, that's off the top of my head.

Comment: @robert4 This is very nice and should get more attention, even today when PowerShell is dominating batch.
I know batch extremely well but did not know this trick and still having some trouble understanding precisely how it works for both cmd and cscript.
Will it get by VBScript? (I'm going to test)
Well done.
If there a web site or some place with more info or tricks like this?

Answer (score 1):

assoc .js=JSfile
ftype jsfile=C:\Windows\System32\Cscript.exe "%1" %*

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, too, and I solved ...

1.- locate `wsh.inf`, the installation file for windows scripting host in `%windir%\inf`

2.- right-click on `wsh.inf` and choose **`install`**.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to run this command to fix the error:

`regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll`