# Phonegap "phonegap build ios" command is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I am new to phonegap, and I tried to create a simple phonegap application.

After installation the phonegap with command line:---

I have created the project successfully but when i trying to run `phonegap build ios` command then a `Error alert` message is coming with `There is no script engine for file extension ".js"` in it.

I am using `Windows 7`, and I installed `Node.js`

**Edit:**

Adding Image----

[image]

Comment: What is your OS? And I assume you installed using nodejs?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, and I installed Node.js

Comment: From the command prompt can you run: `node` command? It should show a new line  starting with the '>' character.

Comment: @Hless: yes, when i type 'node' into console, new line strting with '>'

Answer (score 1):

It might be that Windows is associating the js extension with the wrong program. The PhoneGap build process probably relies on this extension being correctly associated in windows.

Try running this command in the command prompt:
`assoc .js=JSFile`

Then try to rerun your build.

Original answer is here:
[Running Javascript with CScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189269/running-javascript-with-cscript)

Comment: Thanks for answer,  when I am using 'assoc .js=JSFile' I am getting 'Access is deined' message.

Comment: Try running a cmd.exe as administrator. Right click on cmd.exe (or a Shortcut to command prompt) and select 'Run as administrator'. Then try to run the `assoc` command again.

Comment: Also don't forget to hop back out of the command prompt after doing this, and open the command prompt as a 'normal' user. Otherwise file permissions might get a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes it's done now but still facing same problem as I mentioned in image.

Comment: Did you reopen command line after executing the command? It might be needed for windows to pick up the change.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37962/discussion-between-hless-and-ind)