# Run JavaScript in a Windows Command Line

Tags: javascript, command, line, wsh

This is something I only found out about today is that JavaScript can be run through a windows command line.

So I found out that to run a javascript file in windows cmd.exe you use cscript.

My hworld.js file only has one line

```
print('hello world');
```

I try to run this through the command line with

```
cscript /Prog/hworld.js
```

It didn't run with the error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object Expected
```

Are there steps i need to follow before simply cscript running a one line javascript file.

I was under the impression that JavaScript will just run out the box.

PS. Java is the development environment set up for the computer I am trying this on, installed and functional

Comment: You may also find useful [how to combine cscript javascript code into a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29697508/1348138)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right command to print text in the console is

```
WScript.echo("your text");
```

The rest works pretty much like javascript.

Comment: Whaaaaaaaat, I have not found any documentation on syntax differences. Is there a link where I can look for other inconsistencies when running javascript in the console? Thanks a bunch