# How to turn a file into a string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, file, readfile

I am attempting to convert a text file (on my machine) into a string. What is the best/simplest way to do this?
I am looking for a basic function that would look like this:

```
function fileToString(filepath) {
   //this returns a string with the contents of the file
}
```

How should I do this?

EDIT: I now know that there is another question that asks this, but I didn't understand that question so I asked it in different words.

Comment: There's no such a basic function, JS (in browsers) can't directly access user's local drive system. You'd need an input type of file and FileReader API to achieve what you need. Search for these.

Comment: Are you using node.js?

Comment: There are couple existing answers https://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+read+file+as+string (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) ... Or add nodejs for node versions... Or you even can go to old days and use CScript to run JavaScript like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840252/writing-utf8-text-to-file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need node.js for that and this code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./myFile').toString()
```

Comment: fs.readFileSync('./myFile', 'utf8') returns a string. No need the .toString()
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: Exactly! That's why it's a better practice to use the function as it is designed adding 'utf8' as encoding option. Otherwise, it returns a buffer that you have to convert into a string. Why would you ask the function to return a buffer when it can return the type you want?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) for that. The code would be:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileName = "myFile.txt";
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(fileName, "utf8");
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `readFile` does not return file contents. On the other hand `readFileSync` does (but not a string but a buffer).

Comment: "If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer." from the nodejs docs https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options.  Sheesh.

Comment: I believe I have fixed it now @Mark - but the docs were a little unclear. Should it be `string ` or `utf-8`?

Comment: (filename, "utf8")

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in Javascript (browser based), as it does not have access to the file system.
You have to use NodeJs for the same.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('DATA', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});
```

This willl print the contents of the file. Store the contents in a variable. JS has a `.toString()` function which can do what you want.

Comment: Saying that "You cannot do this in Javascript" is incorrect and can be misleading for beginners. I think it's better to say that the browser-based JS runtime systems do not support FileSystem access. Node.js, another JS runtime system (not browser-based), supports that.

Comment: Funny thing that it is possible to read files with locally running JavaScript for almost 20 years now on Windows...

Comment: That's true, good point.

Comment: Apparently, reading wasn't enough.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov did you mean that browser-based JS can read files? IF yes, then how? I am just curious

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev No, NodeJS is not the first command line runner for JavaScript available on Windows - CScript/WScript where there before 2000, .Net compiler (jsc) 
 is there since about 2001 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET). You can find samples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881184/run-javascript-in-a-windows-command-line or if you need more info MSDN contains plenty as well as SO. Search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=cscript%20command%20javascript

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev there is also [HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) that let you run HTML pages with script as local apps with mostly full access to local resources (since 1999).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Interesting! Yep, now I recall that there were some "script" or "scenarios" files in windows and their icon was literally a script written on papyrus or something :D

Answer (score -1):

Just like how Nurbol Alpysbayev and Ashay Mandwarya said in their answers, you'll need to write Javascript for a Runtime System that supports native FileSystem access. Runtime Systems embedded in browsers (the classical way JS that runs on the browser) do not support that.

Node.js, a popular JS Runtime System, that supports so may be used. Your code for Node.js may look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function fileToString(filepath) {
   fs.readFile(filepath, (err, data) => {
       if (err) throw err;

       return data;
   });
}
```

Comment: There is really need for yet another identical answer here in addition to plenty of other similar posts on simiar questions... At least without saying something new.

Comment: I answered exactly as the OP requested. No one wrote code just how the OP wanted it in form of a function.

Comment: Mind explaining why you downvoted my answer even though I provided something in a different format, based on the request of the OP, which no one else did in their answers as of now?